# How to interpret random intercept "BLUP" from the sjPlot package?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am using the sjPlot package to estimate my multilevel model and I am loving it. However, I am a bit confused by the output of the random intercept.

**Background:**
My dependent variable is on a scale from 0-100. I fitted a model with lmer with some individual level variables that are all group-mean centered and a random intercept on the country level (12 countries). When I visualize the random effects (just the intercept in my case) like this:

```
sjp.lmer(mymodel3, type="re",
         sort.est = "sort.all",
         y.offset = .4)
```

I get this plot:

[image]

**Question:**
This confuses me a bit. My dependent variable only has values from 0 to 100, so how are there negative values for some countries? What does that mean? And what do the numbers tell me exactly? I was under the impression that having group-mean centered my variables, the intercepts should give me values on the dependent variable scale for a respondent with average predictors (average income, average education etc.) but of course this doesn't make sense with negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `ranef(mymodel3)`, `fixef(mymodel3)`, and `coef(mymodel3)`. The random effects are the deviation from "global average" (i.e. the fixed effects), so when you sum up `ranef` + `fixef` you get `coef`.

Here's an example:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

ranef(fm1)
#> $Subject
#>     (Intercept)        Days
#> 308   2.2585654   9.1989719
#> 309 -40.3985770  -8.6197032
#> 310 -38.9602459  -5.4488799
#> 330  23.6904985  -4.8143313
# ... truncated

fixef(fm1)
#> (Intercept)        Days 
#>   251.40510    10.46729

coef(fm1)
#> $Subject
#>     (Intercept)       Days
#> 308    253.6637 19.6662579
#> 309    211.0065  1.8475828
#> 310    212.4449  5.0184061
#> 330    275.0956  5.6529547
# ... truncatated
```

E.g. Subject 310: -38.9602459 (ranef) + 251.40510 (fixef) = 212.4449 (coef).